# Как добавить js перед закрывающим тегом body?

Tags: битрикс

Как в битрикс добавить скрипт перед body?
версия - http://clip2net.com/s/3NFoJg6

Comment: а можно какой-то развернутый вопрос?
В чем сейчас состоит проблема?

Comment: @Oleksandr, нужно добавить код метрики перед закрывающим тегом body

Answer (score 2):

Сверху в админ.панели сайта есть кнопочка "Шаблон сайта". Далее - "В панели управления". Далее - "Редактировать шаблон". Открывается код шаблона, смотрите в его нижнюю часть.

Ещё можно в админке найти файл:
/bitrix/templates/шаблон_вашего_сайта/footer.php - в нём, как правило, нижняя часть шаблона сайта, то есть закрывающий тег body

Comment: в смысле "попадает в коммент"?? раскомментируйте )) а вообще у Вас почему-то в комменте закрывающие теги body и html, а потом они ещё раз идут, уже без коммента... у Вас с вёрсткой-то всё в порядке?

Comment: по вёрстке жалоб небыло, попросили только добавить код метрики

Comment: ну, если у Вас всё так, как на скриншоте, значит: 1) удаляете верхнее начало комментария <!-- 2) удаляете после скрипта </body></html>-->

Comment: если бы это начало комментария было бы в этом же файле шаблона,  то я бы не спрашивал. Как найти начало комментария?

Comment: ведь на этом скриншоте видно, что других скриптов и комментов нигде нет http://clip2net.com/s/3NFvzR7

Comment: ладно, благодарю за то что подсказали структуру битрикса, ещё с ним не работал